# Database Designing - A Doctor-Patient-Nurse Consultation

Tags: database-design

Good day to everyone.

I'm working on a database design for our school project which is a clinic management system and I am having issues with one particular design, the consultation flow.

Here is how the business works:
 - When the patient enters the clinic, they must tell their chief complaint to the nurse. (*Chief Complaint is how the patient feels ex: Head Ache*)

The nurse will have to evaluate the patient if they need either:

- Medicine
- Bed Rest (Infirmary)
- or a consultation with the doctor

When a patient needs either Medicine or Bed Rest, they will have to record it together with the reason which is the chief complaint but if the nurse decides to set the patient for consultation, the nurse will have to gather the patient's vital signs. (*The Vital Signs are information regarding the patient's current vital status. ex: Blood Pressure, Temperature, etc..*)

When the Doctor receives the vital signs chart, he will then examine the patient and create an SOAP. (*The SOAP is an acronym for Subjective, Objective, Assessment, and Plan*)

The Plan may contain(or even a combination) of the following:
Referral to a different physician, Excuse Letter, Issue Medicine from the clinic, Take a bed rest (infirmary), and other medical documents...

Now to the database part.

Here is my current design:

Flow 1:

```
tbl_Employee & tbl_Patient --> tbl_Case --> tbl_BedRest or tbl_OTC
```

Definition:

- tbl_Employee - contains both the nurse and the doctors information.
- tbl_Case - Contains the chief complaint, who is the patient, and who handled the patient (Mostly nurse's job but the doctor can Issue medicine and Bed rest too based on the business process)
- tbl_otc - Issued medicine to patients.

Flow 2:

```
tbl_Employee & tbl_Patient --> tbl_vitals --> tbl_SOAP --> tbl_consultation
                        |                                      ^   
                        L-----> tbl_Case ----------------------|
```

On our application, we let the doctor create the case and attach it in tbl_consultation to get the complete information of the case.

Will this possibly create a problem?

My analysis:
Probably since both nurse and doctor can issue medicine and since the nurse is the first one to face the patient, the nurse gets to create the case and send it over to the doctor, that means, the nurse ID is the one attached in the case giving the doctor no option to issue bed rest or medicine.

what do you guys think? any proposed structure?

Comment: Can you give a reference for this flow design approach?

Comment: Nurses get sick, too.